# Is there a Java database framework that supports remote data management on iOS and Android

Tags: database, jdbc, orm, restlet

I am currently using RESTlets to field REST requests and JDBC to enter that data into a mysql database.  As my mobile app is growing JDBC is becoming unmanageable.  Is there a Java database framework that will work well to manage requests coming from iOS and Android devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESTlets with Hibernate or JDBC seems to work